# when do i need to explicitly save an object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a method

after_create :create_slug

```
def create_slug
  self.slug = "#{model}-#{make}-#{year}"
end

def update_slug(user)
  user.slug = "#{model}-#{make}-#{year}"
  user.save!
end
```

I am confused when do I need to explicitly save an object.

Comment: sometimes i can just use self.attributes, don't need to save it. while at other times I will have to write `.save!` method. I am just trying to understand when is it needed and why.

Comment: whenever you need to persist to database

Answer (score 0):

When you want to persist it as is and it's in a dirty state.